# Do mysql_list_fields for a Join Query

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am looking to populate an array of all columns that are being viewed in a query lets say

```
    $sql='SELECT a.tutorial_id, a.tutorial_author, b.tutorial_count
    FROM tutorials_tbl a, tcount_tbl b
    WHERE a.tutorial_author = b.tutorial_author';


    function getColoumns($sql) {
         $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM (". $sql."));
  if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
  }
  $fieldnames=array();
  if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $fieldnames[] = $row['Field'];
    }
  }

  return $fieldnames;
    }
```

I cant seem to get it right. Anyone out there who can help me out.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Besides the obvious missing `"`, any error messages? Can you describe your problem in more detail?

Comment: OOPs sorry for that , it should be .$sql) i had tried earlier, this was just how I wrote for the question.
It is qiving a mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHOW COLUMNS` does not allow for a subselect statement according to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html).

You could instead go for a combination of the original query, [`mysql_num_fields()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-fields.php) and [`mysql_field_name()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php):

```
function getColoumns($sql) {
  $result = mysql_query( $sql );
  if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    // return from function here. don't know what value you need.
    return array()
  }

  $fieldnames = array();
  $fieldCount = mysql_num_fields($result);
  for( $i=0; $i<$fieldCount; $i++ ) {
    $fieldnames[] = mysql_field_name( $result , $i );
  }

  return $fieldnames;
}
```

<sup>Besides, take a look at [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1169798) and/or make sure the query is not malicious!</sup>

Comment: Could not run query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT a.tutorial_id, a.tutorial_author,b.tutorial_count FROM tuto' at line 1

Comment: @GeoffreyMureithi Sorry, didn't read your question carefully enough. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks It worked,
And I think you forgot the 
**return array();**